# Show on Console the dynamic changes of a .txt file in C++

Tags: c++, file, io

Here is my requirement: "**I need to show to the user on a Console window, the output of a .txt file which will be modified continuously by a Third party application**"

I have this code from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/):

```
// reading a text file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("test_results.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( myfile.good() )
    {
      getline (myfile,line);
      cout << line << endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;
}
```

Do I need any sort of time counter to read that file at certain regular intervals of time? Guide me, thanks in advance...

Comment: The typical solution to this is to watch for changes on the file. Doing this is platform dependent though. Which platform are you targeting?

Comment: @sftrabbit: thanks for your comment, I want it to be platform independent, though at present its dedicated to Linux env. Yeah **to watch for changes on the file** for this what exactly do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches.

- Platform-dependent

  Use API, like `inotify` in Linux
- Platform-independent

  Query fs about file modifications, for example using `boost::filesystem`
  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#last_write_time

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its not clear to me, can you please show me regarding usage of `inotify` in the above source code?

Comment: @highlander141 I've never used it on my own, but there are tutorials like this:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-ubuntu-inotify/index.html

Comment: @highlander141 also I've found c++ wrapper http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=inotify-cxx&page=doc&lang=en